# How can I add post to Custom post type from an array?

Tags: php, wordpress, import

**Problem: I created lists with {CityName} and {Departments of City} two column in Excell. Cities are categories and departments of city are post.
I want to add post to Custom post type {departments} in WordPress**

**My Question: How can I add post to Custom post type from an array?**

---

**I Tried 3 Way**

**Hard Way**

```
<?php


$departments = array(
    array(
       "title" => "Adana Kozan Tech Office",
       "cityid" => 153 // or city_nicename
    ),
        ...
  );
    foreach($departments as $c) {
        $istname = $c['title'];
        $cityid  = $c['cityid'];
        $station_info = array(
            'post_title'    => wp_strip_all_tags( $istname ),
            'post_content'  => wp_strip_all_tags( $cityid  ),
            'post_type'     => 'departments',
            'post_category' =>  array($cityid),
            'post_status'   => 'publish',
        );

    wp_insert_post($station_info);

}
?>
```

This was hard way for me. Because little complicated and I saw critical errors. And I couldn't, **It didn't worked**. So if you could this way, please don't hesitate to say in comments where I made a mistake.
Note: It worked for adding categories (wp_insert_category).

**Middle Way**
I thought "how the hell we export posts, that way we import". So I added two dummy department with city category. And exported to pc. And I thought of editing that complicated .xml file. But when I was thinking about it, I found a better way.

**Easy Way**
**WP All Import** plugin. Yes.

1. We are preparing in Excell. Then we save it as a .csv extension.
2. We also open it with notepad ++ and convert it with Encoding> Convert to UTF-8 and save it.
3. We enter the WP All Import plugin and determine how to drag it from there step by step, category, content, and which part to add. Next next. Finish

Comment: If you narrow this down to a single question you'll have a better chance of getting an answer. Don't use stack overflow for asking people to debug your code. Try to isolate the real question you want answered.

Comment: Thanks, I'll correct and make one question. Sorry but I don't use people to debug my code like you said. I already solved the problem. I am asking here because I think it's worth discussing.

Comment: Also this is my first post on Stack Flow, so excuse me if i had a mistake. I tried to write as clearly as possible.

Comment: I'm trying to help and be constructive. I know it's your first post. I would review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask especially the parts about a good subject, search and research, and how to isolate your problem. Restructure your question to a single question that is very specific. Like "How can I add post to Custom post type from an array?" Include the code you already provided. Also include the code that adds the Custom post type.

Comment: Thanks @bryjohns for your additions